# Error C2447 and expected a declaration issues

Tags: c++

I fixed all I can fix, Now I'm just trying to figure out what is wrong here? Can anyone help me? Trying to find out what is wrong with lines 133-1136, or between 130-135 because this is pasted. I am stuck and I gotta get this done tonight. I've spent weeks doing this now.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//
//CLASS DECLARATION SECTION
//
class EmployeeClass
{
public:
    void ImplementCalculations(string EmployeeName, int hours, double wage);
    void DisplayEmployInformation(void);
    void Addsomethingup(EmployeeClass Emp1, EmployeeClass Emp2, EmployeeClass Emp3);
    string EmployeeName;
    int hours;
    double
        wage;
    double basepay;
    int overtime_hours;
    double overtime_pay;
    double overtime_extra;
    double iTotal_salaries;
    double iIndividualSalary;
    int iTotal_hours;
    int iTotal_OvertimeHours;
};

int main()
{
    system("cls");

    cout << "\nWelcome to the Employee Pay Center\n\n";

    EmployeeClass Emp1;
    EmployeeClass Emp2;
    EmployeeClass Emp3;


    cout << "Enter the first employee's name      = ";
    cin >> Emp1.EmployeeName;
    cout << "\nEnter the hours worked               = ";
    cin >> Emp1.hours;
    cout << "\nEnter their hourly wage         = ";
    cin >> Emp1.wage;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter the second employee's name      = ";
    cin >> Emp2.EmployeeName;
    cout << "\nEnter the hours worked               = ";
    cin >> Emp2.hours;
    cout << "\nEnter their hourly wage         = ";
    cin >> Emp2.wage;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter the third employee's name      = ";
    cin >> Emp3.EmployeeName;
    cout << "\nEnter the hours worked               = ";
    cin >> Emp3.hours;
    cout << "\nEnter their hourly wage         = ";
    cin >> Emp3.wage;


    cout << endl;
    Emp1.ImplementCalculations(Emp1.EmployeeName, Emp1.hours, Emp1.wage);
    Emp2.ImplementCalculations(Emp2.EmployeeName, Emp2.hours, Emp2.wage);
    Emp3.ImplementCalculations(Emp3.EmployeeName, Emp3.hours, Emp3.wage);



    system("pause");
    return 0;


    //This section you will send all three objects to a function that will add up the the following information:
    //- Total Employee Salaries 
    //- Total Employee Hours
    //- Total Overtime Hours

    //The format for this function is the following:
    //- Define a new object.
    //- Implement function call [objectname.functionname(object name 1, object name 2, object name 3)]


} //End of Main Function


void EmployeeClass::ImplementCalculations(string EmployeeName, int hours, double wage){
    //Initialize overtime variables
    overtime_hours = 0;
    overtime_pay = 0;
    overtime_extra = 0;

    if (hours > 40)
    {

        basepay = 40 * wage;
        overtime_hours = hours - 40;
        overtime_pay = wage * 1.5;
        overtime_extra = overtime_hours * overtime_pay;
        iIndividualSalary = overtime_extra + basepay;

    }   // if (hours > 40)
    else
    {

        basepay = hours * wage;
        iIndividualSalary = basepay;

    }
    DisplayEmployInformation();

} //End of Primary Function

void EmployeeClass::DisplayEmployInformation()
{
    // This function displays all the employee output information.

    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "Employee Name ............. = " << EmployeeName << endl;
    cout << "Base Pay .................. = " << basepay << endl;
    cout << "Hours in Overtime ......... = " << overtime_hours << endl;
    cout << "Overtime Pay Amount......... = " << overtime_extra << endl;
    cout << "Total Pay ................. = " << iIndividualSalary << endl;

    void Addsomethingup(EmployeeClass Emp1, EmployeeClass Emp2, EmployeeClass Emp3);

} // END OF Display Employee Information

void Addsomethingup(EmployeeClass Emp1, EmployeeClass Emp2, EmployeeClass Emp3);

{  int(i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    iTotal_salaries = 0;
iTotal_hours = 0;
iTotal_OvertimeHours = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{

    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
    cout << "%%%% EMPLOYEE SUMMARY DATA%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
    cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
    cout << "%%%% Total Employee Salaries ..... =" << iTotal_salaries << endl;
    cout << "%%%% Total Employee Hours ........ =" << iTotal_hours << endl;
    cout << "%%%% Total Overtime Hours......... =" << iTotal_OvertimeHours << endl;
    cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
    cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;

}
system("PAUSE");
return;

} // End of function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop in function Addsomethingup should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
```

Comment: Actually the loops shouldn't be there at all.

Comment: dont know about logic he is applying but can tell roughly, syntax using is wrong

Comment: Yes, The loop was a complete accident. I noticed it almost right away myself. I found my errors and thank you for the help. I got it running like it should now. Thank you warmly.

Comment: You don't have to know anything about the logic ... setting something to 0 three times isn't necessary, nor is printing out the exact same block of data three times.

Answer (score 3):

On line 131, you have extra `;`

```
void Addsomethingup(EmployeeClass Emp1, EmployeeClass Emp2, EmployeeClass Emp3);
{
```

That's an obvious error detected by compiler.

Comment: She also has a declaration of that function in DisplayEmployInformation rather than a call to it.

Comment: Thank you so dearly for you guys help. I found the problem. When I compiled it, it worked, then somehow I think I might have dragged some of my words around on the screen and they landed in some wrong areas. (Does this make sense?) I found my issues, I also had to restart Visual Studio, because it was messing up on me. I thank you so much for those who helped me. :-)

Comment: @OfeliaG.S.Stewart Yes, certainly it makes sense ... we have all made copy/paste errors.